# How can I compile all spell .add files?

Tags: spell-checking

I have two spelling addition files:

- ~/.vim/spell/en.utf-8.add
- ~/.vim/bundle/work/spell/en.utf-8.add

~/.vim/bundle/work is in my 'runtimepath'.

I can run this script to build .spl files for both .add files:

```
mkspell! ~/.vim/spell/en.utf-8.add
mkspell! ~/.vim/bundle/work/spell/en.utf-8.add
```

Without modifying 'spellfile', vim loads both en.utf-8.add.spl and detects words from both files.

Is there a command I can use to build the .spl files for all detected .add files (without having to list them all)?

Comment: I've posted an answer, but I'm curious about the workflow that requires this.  If this is something that you are needing to do regularly it might be an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: I use `zg` to add a word. It goes into the first .add. But sometimes I meant for it to go into the second. (I could set both as 'spellfile' and use `2zg`, but still need a solution for when I accidentally use `zg`.) When I edit the .add files, vim doesn't recognize my changes because they need to be recompiled. Possibly I could move words between files (`zw2zg`?), but compiling seems much more straightforward. Sometimes, my vim config doesn't have the work bundle, so I wanted a single consistent command that ensures my spell files are compiled (which comes up very infrequently).

Comment: I keep my dotfiles (including the en.utf-8.add files but not including the spl files) in git to synchronize my config across several computers. I suspect my problem is that when I pull changes to a .add file, vim doesn't notice because it only autocompiles based on zg/zw/etc commands. So I could use this command after I pull new changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
for d in globpath(&runtimepath, "spell/*.add", 0, 1)
    execute "mkspell! " . fnameescape(d)
endfor
```

This finds all `spell/*.add` files in your `&runtimepath` and executes `:mkspell!` on them.